# How to generate fake traffic in the connected network with maximum send/receive capacity of the installed network card?

Tags: c#, networking

I want to write a code in C# console application to generate fake traffic in my network and show send/receive speed of network card. I want to use maximum capacity of my network card and keep this fake maximum traffic until the application is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure the throughput of your network card, you could use a tool like [iperf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php).

It should be possible to start/stop this tool from within your `C#` application.
By default, [iperf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php) runs the performance test for 10 seconds. This can be adjusted by using the `-t` parameter.

[iperf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php) is written in C++.